# WordPress:- get_the_date() function returning a wrong date

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

This is a Word Press/PHP question (very beginner, I guess). I'm trying to insert a link to the latest blog post followed by a posted date using the following code.

```
<div class="latest_post">
    <ul><li><span class="recent_blog">LATEST POST</span><?php
    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => 1,
        'category' => 71,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '"> <strong>' .   $recent["post_title"].'</strong></a>';
    }
    wp_reset_query();
    ?> (<?php echo get_the_date('Y/m/d'); ?>)</li></ul>
</div><!-- .latest_post -->
```

However, `<?php echo get_the_date('Y/m/d'); ?>` returns a wrong date "(2015/04/23)" which I have no idea where it came from. It's supposed to be (2017/01/02). Could anyone help me find out where it went wrong? Or, any other way to get the correct date fetched?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: based on the reference:- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/   (Retrieve the date on which the post was written.)  . I think it's returning  a  post date. so if you want correct date use `<?php echo date ('Y/m/d');?>`

Comment: Thanks, I've tried '<?php echo date ('Y/m/d');?>' but this returned today's date, not 2017/01/02.

Comment: I want a published date of the latest post (which is 2017/01/02). And, I want the date to be auto-updated every time a new post goes live.

Comment: Thank you, your code has resolved my problem. Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually based on the reference :- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/

***(It Retrieve the date on which the post was written.)***

So either provide a post id into this function to get that particular Post date

Or

If you want current date then you can use:-

```
<?php echo date('Y/m/d');?>
```

I think you have to do like below:-

```
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ) {
   echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '"> <strong>' .   $recent["post_title"].'</strong></a>';
   echo get_the_date('Y/m/d',$recent["ID"]);
}
```

Comment: @Joey Some info on why that "wrong date" you refer to (2015/04/23) was displayed instead of your expected date for the post (2017/01/02):  The **get_the_date** behavior is to _always_ return a date, so if a post ID not given to a **get_the_date** call and you're not in a context where posts can be obtained (i.e. is_date() ), then as a last resort **get_the_date** will use the `post_date` field from the `wp_posts` table (in Wordpress DB) for the page itself (note that Wordpress Pages are also stored in the `wp_posts` table but have a `post_type` of `page`). Hope this is useful.

Answer (score 1):

You must use it like as above.

```
<?php echo get_the_date( $format, $post_id ); ?>
```

`$format`
(string) (optional) PHP date format.
Default: the date_format option ('Date Format' on Settings > General panel)

`$post_id`
(integer) (optional) The ID of the post you'd like to fetch. By default the current post is fetched.
Default: null

Comment: Thanks, adding the post ID means that the date cannot be auto-updated when the next post goes live?

Answer (score 1):

Try this with postID

```
<?php $pfx_date = get_the_date( $format, $post_id ); ?>
```

Refere Following links :

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_date

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date

Answer (score 1):

It looks, based upon the documentation (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_date)

That "retrieves the date the **current** $post was written" so that the date: (2015/04/23) might refer to the active page where you are creating the link of the post you are on.

If you are able to get the post id (of the new post), you will be able to get the correct date:- `get_the_date( $format, $post_id )`

Comment: Thank you! This echo get_the_date('Y/m/d',$recent["ID"]); worked perfectly, fetching the posted date. Thanks heaps!!!